# Out of 3n consecutive positive integers....

Tags: probability

Out of 3n consecutive positive integers, 3 are chosen at random without replacement. The probability that the sum of these numbers is divisible by 3 is???

Answer (score 3):

Colour the numbers congruent to $0$ modulo $3$ blue, the ones congruent to $1$ white, and the ones congruent to $2$ red.

There are $\binom{3n}{3}$ equally likely ways to choose $3$ numbers.

We now count the favourables. These are (i) the choices where all chosen numbers  have the same colour,
 and (ii) the choices where the numbers  all have different colours.

There are $3\binom{n}{3}$ choices of Type (i) and $\binom{n}{1}^3$ choices of Type (ii).